# Get more information when "Visual Studio is busy"

Tags: visual-studio-2022

Visual Studio 2022 happens to be busy with something. It pops up with the famous "Visual Studio is busy" message. This is really not helpful as it does not say what it is actually doing. Is there a log or something where I can find more information?

I am not looking for advice like "Try disabling extension xy". I want to know how to get more information. The popup also says "We are sending a report to Microsoft", but I would like to see that report too. I might be able to fix the problem by myself.

Comment: Open up a second instance of VS; then, in the second instance, attach its debugger to the first `devenv.exe` instance (using the .NET 4.x debugger) and click the Break button - then load symbols, and then take a look at the `Debug > Windows > Tasks` window to see all running `Task<T>` operations.